# SSMS: Trying to find the ip address of a connecting server

Tags: sql, ip, ssms

We have an offsite server that we pull data from but they have changed there IP address.
I'm new to using Server management studio (2014) and am having trouble finding the offsite server ip information on ssms that I can change. Where would I look to find this information?

Any advice is appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are connected to the server. Try running this in SSMS:

```
select CONNECTIONPROPERTY('client_net_address')
```

Comment: I'm not connected to the client's server so this will just give me my ip address.
Is there somewhere on SSMS where it will tell me "hey, this is the IP address of the server/ table your trying to connect to, you can also change the ip address here."?

Comment: SSMS is just a client which you need to provide server information to. So if you cannot connect to the server, you cannot deduce that information using SSMS,